# How to get extension number of user logging in ring central page

Tags: apex, soql, salesforce1-app, call-center

Hi friends i got a requirement to get the phone number of user logging in sfdc ring central page.But i didn't find any ways to capture.

So,we are try to get phone number of user logging  in sfdc Itself.Please provide your suggestions or better ways to find out.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a login flow to achieve this, as the user logs in the login flow will check if the phone number field is populated on the user record and if not, prompt them to enter it before allowing them to complete the login.

This will enforce phone number has to be completed before logging in. Refer to the 'collect and update user data' example in the link below.

https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Login-Flows

Comment: But is it possible to retrieve multiple numbers.Because in some rare cases user logged with multiple numbers means more than 1.@adam.sellers